# How to run iPhone application on iPad Mini in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ipad-mini

I am trying to run iPhone app in Xcode on iPad mini - as it support iPhone compatibility app. This works on iPad 3 but not on iPad mini where I got this error from xCode:

```
2016-04-08 11:27:52.190 My app [6365:942940] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/path/to/my/app.app> (loaded)' with name 'SomeController' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186186084 0x196b340e4 0x186185fc4 0x18ad10b80 0x18aecfce0 0x18ab94294 0x18ab93440 0x18ab91c00 0x18e365640 0x18613e360 0x18613d468 0x18613b668 0x186069664 0x18a97398c 0x18a96e984 0x100094ab4 0x1971a2a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I didn't find any informations about this problem. Is there workaround how to run iPhone app with Xcode on iPad mini?

If I use universal mode for app running its working properly but I want to restrict for iPhone only.

Thanks
Marekkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got a typo in 'Main.storyboard**c**'
and that is not device-specific

Comment: I find out that too, problem is that for iPhone app si running without errors and for iPad (big one) too, just with the iPad mini there is this problem - in General settign there is Main.storyboard without c so I have no idea from where the c comes

Answer (score 0):

Try check out the xib file in the file inspector. Mayby the app is not supported by iPad mini?

Comment: I am requesting app not supported with iPad at all and I am trying to run it in iPhone version on iPad mini. With iPad (normal) everyting is running as it should be